# Laravel: Skip some params from route or call Controller@show without adding 'static' adding

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

> Laravel: 5.4

It works, But I want to know if there are other pro-solutions.

I have a route like this

```
Route::get('{any}-a{id}', function($any, $id) {
   return ArticleController::show($id);
})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'any' => '.*']);
```

But this required `public **static** function show($id)`

Are there any other solution to call **non-static** function from Route, or just skip the **$any** params like `->compact('id')` (in Route), or:
`Route::get('#something-I-don't-know#-a{id}'), function(**$id**) { ... })`?

I want to keep the non-static *show* function because it come from Route:resource of another Route: `route('articles.show',$article->id)`. I don't want to add the $any param.

Thanks for your time and your answers :D

Comment: You can use `scope` in define method like `scopeShow`.

Comment: @Saman, but I already have a `show` function. And I think `scope` is belong to Query Builder, not to return a view.

Comment: yes you right , my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do this instead of calling static methods:

```
app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController')->show($id);
```

Full code would be like this:

```
Route::get('{any}-a{id}', function($any, $id) {
   return app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController')->show($id);
})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'any' => '.*']);
```